# К получить доступ к значению списка в pymongo

Tags: python, pymongo

Имеется такая запись в бд, как получить в переменную значение money?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Запись

```
self.farmcoll.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id})[f'pigs.money']
```

выдает ошибку

```
Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'pigs.money'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помогла такая запись

```
for i in self.farmcoll.find_one({"_id": ctx.author.id})['pigs']:
    if i['number'] == one_id:
        money += i['money']
        hp += i['hp']
```